# AppleScript for Excel to select/copy all cells?

Tags: applescript, ms-office

Applescript can tell Excel to select a specific range of cells, e.g.

`select (range "A1:B20")`

and you can copy cells:

`copy (range "A1:B20")`

However, how can you tell Excel to select all the cells in a worksheet, or to copy all the cells in a worksheet? It seems to require a specific range. However, of course, when you are working with Excel directly you can just press cmd+A to select all.

Answer (score 1):

found this on Macscripter.net I think it is what you are looking for:

```
tell application "Microsoft Excel"
   tell active sheet
       select used range
   end tell
end tell
```